# Enabled Scrollbar when TableLayoutPanel is Disabled

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` with a number of `TextBoxes` and `GroupBoxes`. I have set this `TableLayoutPanel.Enabled = false`.This Disables all the `TextBoxes` and `Groupboxes` and the `Scrollbar`. Is their anyway i can  `enable` the `scrollbar` even if the `TableLayouPanel.Enabled = false`?

Comment: Instead of disabling the TableLayoutPanel itself you could loop through the child controls and disable/enable them as appropriate, then the scrollbar would remain active.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this automatically, you can subscribe to the `EnabledChanged` event of your `TableLayoutPanel`.  You can subscribe to the event using the designer, or with the following line of code:

```
tableLayoutPanel.EnabledChanged += tableLayoutPanel_EnabledChanged;
```

Then, from the event handler, we can simply set the enabled property of the scroll bar to match the enabled property value of the TableLayoutPanel:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scrollbar.Enabled = tableLayoutPanel.Enabled;
}
```

Now, whenever the enabled state of the TableLayoutPanel changes, the scroll bar enabled state will be updated to match.